# Mirroring PowerShell modules repository in to Artifactory

Tags: artifactory, powershell-module

We want to mirror PowerShell module repository in to our Artifactory instance as a Virtual repo, to have the ability to obtain needed modules from our Azure VM

Has any one done that before? Is there any documentation on how to mirror PowerShell modules into Artifactory?